# Photoshop shows the transparency checker pattern through non-transparent layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, glitch

There is a layer with fully-white, 255 alpha, no mask, 100% opacity and 100% fill, and yet, the transparent grid shows through:

[image: Transparency grid shows through the black pixels]

It is faint, but it's confirmed to be there: I captured it with `Win+Shift+S`, pasted and levelled the image until they show clearly. It is the transparency checker pattern.

I've also confirmed it's a visual glitch: the info tab shows 100% opacity in the black pixels, and dragging it to the mask button generates a mask that's 100% white on the black pixels.

Additionally, exporting a PNG out of that layer generates a image that displays correctly in other viewers and works for all purposes.

Adding a fill color layer underneath fixes the display.

I've tried to check my color profile settings and nothing fixes this.

It's just a visual glitch that ain't making it impossible to work, but it's also impossible to ignore and it's slowly becoming annoying as hell.

Anybody's seen this before?

Comment: Yeah well the transparency grid does not care about color profiles. You can set the blend using gamma of 1 in color settings but again if you want to be accurate put your own background in. The problem is that alpha blending is actually badly defined as to what it should mean.

Comment: Also try turning off your GPU acceleration

Comment: Hi. Can you share the actual PNG, or a part of it. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BillyKerr actually, I can't. :-(

Comment: @joojaa Didn't work.

Comment: Well there is not much we can do beyond this. Try making a new file that exhibits the problem and share that, not the actual file you have.